# Where to set maximumImageFileSize of angular-summernote?

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I need to limit the file size of uploaded image through angular-summernote. [This](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/920) github issue says we need to specify size in bytes for 'maximumImageFileSize' in its settings.js. Though even after specifying the size, summernote is not limiting upload size. There is no documentation regarding image size limit, hence if anyone has implemented this successfully, please point out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in an Angular 1 project. In our html file we added summernote with the **config** attribute containing the maximum size value in bytes (ex: 5242880 for 5Mo).

```
<summernote config="options" lang="fr-FR"></summernote>
```

In our controller we define a scope variable `$scope.options`

```
$scope.options = {
  maximumImageFileSize: <Your limit size>,
  callbacks: {
     onImageUploadError: function () {
     alert('Size too big');
    }
   }
};
```